# 3 Variable Diophantine Equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all integer solutions to $$x^4 + y^4 + z^3 = 5$$ I don't know how to proceed, since it has a p-adic and real solution for all $p$.
I think that the only one is (2, 2, -3) and the trivial ones that come from this, but I can't confirm it.

Comment: It definitely has integer solutions as well, e.g. $(2,2,-3)$.

Comment: Not trained in Diophantine equations in the slightest, but first thing I notice is that you can simplify to $x^2+y^2+z^3=5$ and only concern yourself with positive x,y. Then you'll get four solutions for every solution to this new one. (e.g. in Prometheus' solution, you can take either or both 2's to be -2).

Comment: That many question marks reads to me like mockery or shouting, @WillJagy

Comment: I did a small computer search for $|x|,|y|,|z|\le 100$. The only solutions are $(\pm2,\pm 2, -3)$,

Comment: For $x\ne y$, there are no solutions for $|x|, |y|\le 1000$

Comment: Some ideas: The equation $x^2+y^2+z^3=5$ has very many solutions (e.g. $(11,3,5)$ and$(14,5,6)$) but perhaps one can parametrize its solutions and then find which ones have square $x$ and $y$. There is the factorization $(ix-y)(ix+y)=(z-\sqrt[3]{5})(z-\omega \sqrt[3]{5})(z-\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{5})$ in the splitting field of $X^6+25=0$, which happens to have class number one.

Comment: How would one proceed? I don't have much of a background in algebraic number theory.

Answer (score 3):

Solutions to $$ z^3 + 5 = k^4 + s^2  $$ are reasonably frequent

```
 September 27  

z: 3          n: 32       k: 2     sq: 4  sq_sq: 2  diff  0
z: 5          n: 130       k: 3     sq: 7  sq_sq: 2  diff  3
z: 15          n: 3380       k: 2     sq: 58  sq_sq: 7  diff  9
z: 20          n: 8005       k: 9     sq: 38  sq_sq: 6  diff  2
z: 68          n: 314437       k: 23     sq: 186  sq_sq: 13  diff  17
z: 83          n: 571792       k: 4     sq: 756  sq_sq: 27  diff  27
z: 93          n: 804362       k: 19     sq: 821  sq_sq: 28  diff  37
z: 101          n: 1030306       k: 3     sq: 1015  sq_sq: 31  diff  54
z: 168          n: 4741637       k: 31     sq: 1954  sq_sq: 44  diff  18
z: 405          n: 66430130       k: 73     sq: 6167  sq_sq: 78  diff  83
z: 431          n: 80062996       k: 94     sq: 1410  sq_sq: 37  diff  41
z: 488          n: 116214277       k: 103     sq: 1914  sq_sq: 43  diff  65
z: 684          n: 320013509       k: 25     sq: 17878  sq_sq: 133  diff  189
z: 765          n: 447697130       k: 103     sq: 18307  sq_sq: 135  diff  82
z: 848          n: 609800197       k: 9     sq: 24694  sq_sq: 157  diff  45
z: 1005          n: 1015075130       k: 79     sq: 31243  sq_sq: 176  diff  267
z: 1221          n: 1820316866       k: 11     sq: 42665  sq_sq: 206  diff  229
z: 1391          n: 2691419476       k: 126     sq: 49390  sq_sq: 222  diff  106
z: 1871          n: 6549699316       k: 130     sq: 79146  sq_sq: 281  diff  185
z: 2480          n: 15252992005       k: 247     sq: 107382  sq_sq: 327  diff  453
z: 2768          n: 21207928837       k: 247     sq: 132234  sq_sq: 363  diff  465
z: 2888          n: 24087491077       k: 39     sq: 155194  sq_sq: 393  diff  745
z: 3485          n: 42326109130       k: 409     sq: 119763  sq_sq: 346  diff  47
z: 4076          n: 67717750981       k: 103     sq: 260010  sq_sq: 509  diff  929
z: 5636          n: 179024699461       k: 625     sq: 162594  sq_sq: 403  diff  185
z: 5763          n: 191401729952       k: 466     sq: 379796  sq_sq: 616  diff  340
z: 5925          n: 208000828130       k: 509     sq: 375337  sq_sq: 612  diff  793
z: 7965          n: 505309357130       k: 691     sq: 526613  sq_sq: 725  diff  988
z: 12308          n: 1864500322117       k: 1167     sq: 98786  sq_sq: 314  diff  190
z: 14213          n: 2871159161602       k: 1269     sq: 527159  sq_sq: 726  diff  83
z: 14991          n: 3368928644276       k: 1318     sq: 592730  sq_sq: 769  diff  1369
z: 15615          n: 3807377733380       k: 1052     sq: 1607042  sq_sq: 1267  diff  1753
z: 17496          n: 5355700839941       k: 1423     sq: 1120430  sq_sq: 1058  diff  1066
z: 18063          n: 5893450576052       k: 686     sq: 2381594  sq_sq: 1543  diff  745
z: 19923          n: 7907955283472       k: 1292     sq: 2263076  sq_sq: 1504  diff  1060
z: 22901          n: 12010562298706       k: 571     sq: 3450255  sq_sq: 1857  diff  1806
z: 23445          n: 12886966846130       k: 1111     sq: 3370967  sq_sq: 1836  diff  71
z: 24693          n: 15056414740562       k: 667     sq: 3854671  sq_sq: 1963  diff  1302
z: 24995          n: 15615626874880       k: 464     sq: 3945792  sq_sq: 1986  diff  1596
z: 27663          n: 21168877523252       k: 1862     sq: 3024646  sq_sq: 1739  diff  525
z: 33180          n: 36528273432005       k: 1831     sq: 5028778  sq_sq: 2242  diff  2214
z: 35324          n: 44076756492229       k: 705     sq: 6620402  sq_sq: 2573  diff  73
z: 37388          n: 52263284795077       k: 2111     sq: 5692494  sq_sq: 2385  diff  4269
z: 38733          n: 58109000778842       k: 2203     sq: 5878381  sq_sq: 2424  diff  2605
z: 51293          n: 134950439050762       k: 2973     sq: 7538389  sq_sq: 2745  diff  3364
z: 53871          n: 156338201695316       k: 2602     sq: 10511890  sq_sq: 3242  diff  1326
z: 54344          n: 160492523139589       k: 2975     sq: 9064158  sq_sq: 3010  diff  4058
z: 61200          n: 229220928000005       k: 1367     sq: 15024278  sq_sq: 3876  diff  902
z: 61733          n: 235262196719842       k: 981     sq: 15308039  sq_sq: 3912  diff  4295
z: 63045          n: 250583197816130       k: 2803     sq: 13742407  sq_sq: 3707  diff  558
z: 68493          n: 321320597819162       k: 3911     sq: 9346411  sq_sq: 3057  diff  1162
z: 70995          n: 357835390324880       k: 4184     sq: 7168012  sq_sq: 2677  diff  1683
z: 80988          n: 531204838990277       k: 2887     sq: 21488054  sq_sq: 4635  diff  4829
z: 85020          n: 614558602008005       k: 3623     sq: 21030058  sq_sq: 4585  diff  7833
z: 86111          n: 638522048185636       k: 4820     sq: 9938694  sq_sq: 3152  diff  3590
z: 91551          n: 767342543357156       k: 4496     sq: 18940330  sq_sq: 4352  diff  426
z: 96200          n: 890277128000005       k: 3847     sq: 25908582  sq_sq: 5090  diff  482
jagy@phobeusjunior:
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
z: 100221     n: 1006644663093866     k: 2573     sq: 31029275  sq_sq: 5570  diff  4375
z: 100980     n: 1029689061192005     k: 3617     sq: 29300722  sq_sq: 5413  diff  153
z: 100995     n: 1030147992574880     k: 5014     sq: 19952908  sq_sq: 4466  diff  7752
z: 121725     n: 1803596357953130     k: 1423     sq: 42420467  sq_sq: 6513  diff  1298
z: 125973     n: 1999090319542322     k: 5843     sq: 28870511  sq_sq: 5373  diff  1382
z: 126060     n: 2003235041016005     k: 4993     sq: 37171598  sq_sq: 6096  diff  10382
z: 130131     n: 2203648395038096     k: 5644     sq: 34480780  sq_sq: 5872  diff  396
z: 140480     n: 2772320878592005     k: 4617     sq: 48144778  sq_sq: 6938  diff  8934
z: 148191     n: 3254359196531876     k: 340     sq: 57046874  sq_sq: 7552  diff  14170
z: 160163     n: 4108531157450752     k: 3712     sq: 62599296  sq_sq: 7911  diff  15375
z: 161988     n: 4250583285982277     k: 7991     sq: 13152346  sq_sq: 3626  diff  4470
z: 163661     n: 4383647270173786     k: 1013     sq: 66201165  sq_sq: 8136  diff  6669
z: 165375     n: 4522822787109380     k: 5828     sq: 58044482  sq_sq: 7618  diff  10558
z: 165900     n: 4566034179000005     k: 5183     sq: 62003122  sq_sq: 7874  diff  3246
z: 176028     n: 5454378397973957     k: 7847     sq: 40778026  sq_sq: 6385  diff  9801
z: 199440     n: 7932987984384005     k: 6647     sq: 77336182  sq_sq: 8794  diff  1746
z: 200405     n: 8048698481430130     k: 5871     sq: 82828807  sq_sq: 9101  diff  606
z: 217475     n: 10285561814046880     k: 662     sq: 101416812  sq_sq: 10070  diff  11912
z: 220035     n: 10653082808542880     k: 94     sq: 103213772  sq_sq: 10159  diff  8491
z: 253023     n: 16198694022523172     k: 8032     sq: 109712186  sq_sq: 10474  diff  7510
z: 255080     n: 16596985896512005     k: 11343     sq: 6530798  sq_sq: 2555  diff  2773
z: 257363     n: 17046622002731152     k: 10524     sq: 69137876  sq_sq: 8314  diff  15280
z: 267188     n: 19074398313188677     k: 5871     sq: 133739714  sq_sq: 11564  diff  13618
z: 272288     n: 20187637882191877     k: 11849     sq: 21813174  sq_sq: 4670  diff  4274
z: 290516     n: 24519418580108101     k: 3145     sq: 156274074  sq_sq: 12500  diff  24074
z: 293693     n: 25332659542683562     k: 7269     sq: 150135829  sq_sq: 12252  diff  24325
z: 313919     n: 30935191351930564     k: 5260     sq: 173694258  sq_sq: 13179  diff  8217
z: 317283     n: 31940404348304192     k: 7564     sq: 169313176  sq_sq: 13012  diff  1032
```

Comment: That should be expected as 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/3 > 1

Comment: @MayankPandey, no, the meaning of that inequality is that, with $y \geq 0,$ we expect all sufficiently large numbers to have an expression as $x^2 + y^3 + z^4.$ See The Hardy-Littlewood Method by R. C. Vaughan, chapter Eight in the second edition http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/hardy-littlewood-method-2nd-edition?format=HB?format=HB  author http://www.personal.psu.edu/rcv4/

Answer (score 1):

After a careful investigation I present some results which might be helpful in the final resolution of this problem. Lets start with the original equation i.e.
$$x^4+y^4+z^3=5$$
It is easy to see that there is no solution of this equation where $x,y$ and $z$ are all positive. Second if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution then so is $(-x,-y,z)$. From this observations we get that $z<0$. Let rewrite the equation in terms of positive values i.e.
$$x^4+y^4-z^3=5$$
where $x,y$ and $z$ are all positive. This is equivalent to 
$$x^4+y^4=5+z^3$$
From this, one gets 
$$x^4+y^4\equiv z^3\mod(5)$$
First we show that $x\equiv 0\mod(5)$ and $y\equiv 0\mod(5)$ iff $z\equiv 0\mod(5)$. 
If $x\equiv 0\mod(5)$ and $y\equiv 0\mod(5)$ then 
$$x^4+y^4\equiv0\mod(5)\Rightarrow 5+z^3\equiv z^3\equiv0\mod(5)\Rightarrow z\equiv0\mod(5)$$ 
Now let $z\equiv0\mod(5)$ then $$5+z^3\equiv0\mod(5)\Rightarrow x^4+y^4\equiv0\mod(5)$$
However for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ one has $x^4\equiv0\mod(5)$ or $x^4\equiv1\mod(5)$. Therefore
$$x^4+y^4\equiv0\mod(5)\Leftrightarrow x\equiv y\equiv0\mod(5)$$
 However an inspection of our modified equation yields that we can not have simultaneously $x$ and $y$ divisible by $5$ for otherwise $z\equiv0\mod(5)$ and
$$x^4+y^4\equiv0\mod(5^3)\Rightarrow 5+z^3\equiv0\mod(5^3)$$
which is impossible as $5+z^3\equiv 5\mod(5^3)$.
Knowing that $x$ and $y$ can not be simultaneously divisible by $5$ then $z$ is not divisible by $5$ either. Applying Fermat's little theorem we can rewrite the modified equation as
$$zx^4+zy^4\equiv1\mod(5)$$
 Let say without loss of generality $y\equiv0\mod(5)$ and $x^4\equiv1\mod(5)$ then
$$z\cdot 1+z\cdot 0\equiv1\mod(5)\Rightarrow z\equiv1\mod(5)$$

The other exhaustive case would be $x^4\equiv1\mod(5)$ and $y^4\equiv1\mod(5)$ in which case 
$$z\cdot 1+z\cdot 1\equiv1\mod(5)\Rightarrow 2z\equiv1\mod(5)\Rightarrow z\equiv3\mod(5)$$
In this case a direct inspection for $z=3$ would yield $x=\pm 2$ and $y=\pm 2$.

Comment: The diophantine equation has solutions $\pmod n$ for all $n$. Congruences can rule out some solutions, but you won't be able to rule out all but finitely many.